# Android Studio (version 2022.1) Unable to find bundled Java version

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I have been struggling facing that problem in Android studio using Flutter.
[image]
Any solution for that issue?
I am using Windows 10 and tired of searching for that problem and fixing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1

For Windows Users,

Open the terminal and open to the android studio directory

Like,

```
cd C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
```

Then,

```
mklink /D "jre" "jbr”
```

copy the content of jbr and paste the content into jre folder

To resolve the issue after completing the above change, just create a sym link jre -> jbr.
run doctor this commend `‘flutter doctor’` again and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps.

1. Go to C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
2. Go into the jbr file, copy all of them and paste them into the jre file
3. Run flutter doctor.